# Increase the disk size on Debian 11 with btrfs filesystem

Tags: debian, lvm, btrfs

I have a Debian 11 system on VirtualBox VM, and I am now trying to increase its disk size.

I create this Debian 11 with btrfs file system for my main division at the beginning, so right now, it should already run on btrfs system with my existed volume.

What I already done:

use fdisk to create a new section from the volume I added in my vdi file use order `fdisk /dev/sda`, the new section called `/dev/sda4`

and

```
mkfs.btrfs -L extand /dev/sda4
```

to make it a btrfs file system.

so right now:

fdisk -l shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 25 GiB, 26843545600 bytes, 52428800 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A5328659-9CBF-49AE-BF68-F9F4670D45C8

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1050624  2050047   999424  488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   2050048 16775167 14725120    7G Linux LVM
/dev/sda4  16775168 52428766 35653599   17G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/debian--vg-root: 6.03 GiB, 6476005376 bytes, 12648448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/debian--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

btrfs filesystem show :

```
Label: none  uuid: 3ea73e8c-64ac-442c-8c88-2675908cecdd
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 4.68GiB
        devid    1 size 6.03GiB used 6.03GiB path /dev/mapper/debian--vg-root

Label: 'extand'  uuid: ef622e2c-9c19-415e-a8d7-6e60ef448bc2
        Total devices 1 FS bytes used 192.00KiB
        devid    1 size 17.00GiB used 536.00MiB path /dev/sda4
```

df :

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                           990920       0    990920   0% /dev
tmpfs                          201748   20780    180968  11% /run
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root   6324224 5103168         0 100% /
tmpfs                         1008720       0   1008720   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                      481642   87234    369423  20% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523244    3484    519760   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          201744       0    201744   0% /run/user/0
```

What should I do next?

I tried the `resize2fs`, that doesn't work on btrfs file system, and I don't know how and where to mount the /dev/sda4 to use `btrfs filesystem resize` order.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to inform you, but it seems you made quite a lot of mess.

The issue started long before you did extension even, already at install.

Whole point of ZFS (and its filesystems) and BTRFS (and it subvolumes) is to replace obsolete last century ideas like LVM.

Both ZFS and BTRFS are their "own LVMs", ie you don't need one, so why do I see your root / BTRFS pool instantiated from `/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root` LVM device (which I presume is layered on top of `/dev/sda3`) ?

Unless you have some very specific reason to do such silly layering, this is quite wrong.

Given your visor (vbox) and single disk vm system, your process should have been:

1. increase disk size in the visor
2. instruct guest to rescan the disk size (or whole storage bus ) - if disk size did not increase already - you can check in kernel log through dmesg(1)
3. edit partition table and stretch last partition (hosting your root)
4. after your partition is stretched you can issue: `# btrfs filesystem resize max /`

Instead you did:

1. Installed BTRFS on top of LVM

Some time later:

1. Increased disk size in the visor
2. Instructed guest to rescan the disk size
3. **Added new partition(!)** to the partition table
4. **Formatted this new partition to new BTRFS pool and labelled it "extand" (cool name by the way :))**

**How to fix it**

Start a new VM. If you are on Windows I suggest you to get rid of VirtualBox and replace it with HyperV, if you can (you need windows 10 something) management and performance characteristics and virtual hw support are day and night between them, in favor of HyperV that is. Plus your HyperV VM can run even if you are logged out.

Ensure following layout:

```
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  ???????  ???????  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2   ???????  ???????  ???????  488M Linux filesystem # I assume this is /boot)
/dev/sda3   ???????  ???????  ???????   **G Linux filesystem # <- this will be your btrfs
```

If you need swap either put it on different disk, or, if you know size beforehand, put it in front of btrfs partition to minimize hassle:

```
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  ???????  ???????  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2   ???????  ???????  ???????  488M Linux filesystem # I assume this is /boot)
/dev/sda3   ???????  ???????  ???????   7G Linux filesystem # <- swap prepends btrfs
/dev/sda4   ???????  ???????  ???????   **G Linux filesystem # <- this will be your btrfs
```

Once you consume all the space on `/dev/sda3` (`/dev/sda4` respectively) you just extend the disk in visor, and reedit partition size with `fdisk`, `parted`, `cgdisk` or what have you, an then do `btrfs filesystem resize` on the `/`.

Comment: why do u think btrfs makes lvm obsolete? you can have lvm -> btrfs without any problems. I don't know of any way how you can extend a btrfs over multiple disks like you can do when using lvm.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux [`btrfs device add ...`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-device.html) makes it trivial to "extend a btrfs over multiple disks".

Comment: @rickhg12hs i thought that command is to add more disks to a raid0 or raid1 - this is really somethink i have to get into it. So instead of partitions then I have to work with subvolders only?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I am fully aware you can have BTRFS on top of LVM, in some special setups that is the only way even. Now please explain to me what exactly do you gain by introducing the LVM to the mix in the normal circumstances? What problem or what benefits introduction of one very complex layer under another very complex layer brings?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, @AlexOnLinux this is unix, you can have chicken under the cheese under salad on top of bread on top of pizza on top of ricecake. But even if you can, it does not mean you should.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux yes that is "traditional ZFS way", which is understood implicitly. As BTRFS takes partial inspiration from ZFS, it is understood similarly implicitly. In these new FS you have two things that are completely diconnected at managerial level, and it works as if magic:

Comment: @AlexOnLinux you have: - storage - these are your disks; - subvolumes/filesystems - these are your unix namespace

Comment: @AlexOnLinux disks in pool act like "free space pool" and subovlumes take space from it as they see fit. Maximum size of a subvolume thus loses all meaning - it will have as much size as it will need to function. It's kinda weird, but you can imagine it as subvolumes having size of the data in each of them, while each subvolume has same amount of free space that is free in the whole pool. So subvolumes compete for free space from pool. I hope it makes sense. Also forget about partitions, that is bad thinking, partitions are partitions, subvolumes are subvolumes.

Comment: Thx guys, thats awsome. I really didn't know about btrfs ability to expand over several disks. That is the reason why i was using lvm. Also i mixed filesystems depending. For example for my vm images i heard it would be better not to use a cow filesystem because of the permament changes in these img Files. But having only to deal with subfolders instead of partition borders is awsome and i feel incredibly stupid

Comment: Both BTRFS and ZFS require, especially for "traditional" admins )whatever that means), to give up on some stubbornness.

Comment: As I already explained, in my opinion, specifically in your case, adding device in RAID0/LVM fashion, as suggested by rickhg12hs is overkill, given the subject is plain simple VM. You can get incredibly far with just my method of disk and related partition extension. Even without partition extension, you could still extended the disk and add new partition (sdxy) at the end in RAID0 fashion as rickhg12hs suggest. Or you really could extend by adding whole new disk following rickhg12hs advice proper. If it is for learning all those are fine. For just getting more space, I believe mine is better.

Comment: As you see, BTRFS is perfectly fine with both storage device (partition) size change, and with new disk addition. So pick your poison depending on your needs. Best it is to have experience with as many methods as possible.

Comment: Regarding COW being unsuitable for VMs, that is very complex topic, that depends on lot of your operational context. For example in few of my cases where I have actual SCSI devices passed right into the VMs through fibrechannel SAN from commercial disk array - when the VM is basically talking to it's "very own dedicated hardware disks", the COW performance issue is completely negligible, because the whole storage layer is "real".

Comment: In an KVM, HyperV (or VBox) visor setup, where disk (and subsequently each visor snapshot) is yet another file on visor host on some non stellar filesystem (like Windows NTFS) the performance impact might be severe. But always remember to prefer in-VM BTRFS snapshots over external visor snapshots, ie preallocated zero filled fully sized virtual disk file (so called thick virtual disk) formatted to BTFS, will always outperform "growing" virtual disk file(s) and visor snapshots - such is nature of the thing.